# Add Sample Rcp Application (With View ) Menubar(Created By Own) into Eclipse Default Menubar while Porting Application as Plugin to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

**Input**: RCP Application(with View): 
           *Menubar*::  **List FileFunction Window Help**

**Output**: All these Menu to be Added in Default Menubar of Eclipse when the said RCP application is   Ported as Plugin to Eclipse.

**Note**: Menubar in RCP application is created in ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.java class and not in plugin.xml with the help of FillMenuBar method.

**Problem**: *After Porting the Above Application as Plugin....View is Opening but Menubar of RCP App is not showing up in Menubar of Eclipse*.

***Kindly help out as to How to proceed to solve this Problem***

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So what did you do to move the code in `ApplicationActionBarAdvisor` to the plugin?

Comment: When you copy the code, your ApplicationActionBarAdvisor is no longer called, so you must provide extensions in your plugin.xml to hooh into/contribute to the existing Menubar and Menu's. THis is explained roughly [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions)

Comment: I think writing menu contributions through extension point is not manageable, if we scale up the menu items. Therefore we tried to write our Menu Items on fill menuBar method in ApplicationActionBarAdvisior(Which is working perfectly right when we are creating RCP application, but it is not working when we tried to export this as a plugin into Eclipse.).Also our application can have large number of menu items, so loading all the menus through plugin.xml at the start is also not a good choice. What we are trying to figure out, to load menus when it is required.